# audio waves length change when tempo change [Logic Pro X]

Tags: logic-pro, tempo

I didn't know that I was editing the audio files with the default tempo(120). 
Actually, the original tempo of the song is 140.
When I realized and tried to change it into 140, every piece of waves are disordered and the length are changed too.

How can I change the tempo without affecting the audio files?

What I am looking for is maybe similar with 'wrap' function of Albeton.

Comment: Is this actually affecting the audio?  Does the audio match the tempo that you're using now where it didn't at the previous tempo, or are you finding that the tempo of the recorded parts has changed as well?  If you're not hearing any difference in the audio, then I would guess that it's just a visual change.

Comment: tempo will affect midi regions but not audio. Can you clarify exactly what is happening here?

Comment: Sorry for wrong questioning. Yes it is a visual change and still in the right tempo, and nothing effect to the audio quailty. But as I am mixing about 50 mutiple tracks, it took me about half hour to move all edited waves back to the exact timeline. What actually happened is every pieces of waves are not on the exact timeline.